# ValueError at /cart/chelsea-01920-jersey/ invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'color'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

```
Hi guys im getting this error try to with my models and views

    Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner response = get_response(request) File "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response

response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request) File "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) File "C:\Users\hp\OneDrive\Desktop

\DevProjects\Elsie_Final\carts\views.py", line 57, in UpdateCart cart_item, created = CartItem.objects.get_or_create(cart=cart, item=item) File "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method return 

getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs) File "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 538, in get_or_create return self.get(**kwargs), False File "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 399, in

 get clone = self.filter(*args, **kwargs) File "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 892, in filter return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs) File "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 910, in _filter_or_exclude clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs)) File "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 

1290, in add_q clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases) File "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1318, in _add_q split_subq=split_subq, simple_col=simple_col, File "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1251, in build_filter condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col,

 value) File "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1116, in build_lookup lookup = lookup_class(lhs, rhs) File "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 20, in __init__ self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup() 

File "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_lookups.py", line 115, in get_prep_lookup self.rhs = target_field.get_prep_value(self.rhs) File "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3

\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 966, in get_prep_value return int(value) ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'color'
```

---

models:

```
class CartItem(models.Model):

    cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    variations = models.ManyToManyField(Variation, null=True, blank=True)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    notes = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    line_total = models.DecimalField(default=0.00,max_digits=1000, decimal_places=2)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.item.title

class VariationManager(models.Manager):

    def all(self):
        return super(VariationManager,self).filter(active=True)

    def sizes(self):
        return self.all().filter(category='size')

    def colors(self):
        return self.all().filter(category='color')

    def packages(self):
        return self.all().filter(category='package')

VAR_CATEGORIES = (
    ('size','size'),
    ('color', 'color'),
    ('package', 'package'),
)

class Variation(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=120, choices=VAR_CATEGORIES, default='size')
    image = models.ForeignKey(ItemImage, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=100, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

    objects = VariationManager()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

view:

```
def UpdateCart(request, slug):
    request.session.set_expiry(600)
    try:
        the_id = request.session['cart_id']
    except:
        #create cart
        new_cart = Cart()
        new_cart.save()
        request.session['cart_id'] = new_cart.id
        the_id = new_cart.id
    cart = Cart.objects.get(id=the_id)
    try:
        item = Item.objects.get(slug=slug)
    except Item.DoesNotExist:
        pass

    item_var = [] #product variation    
    if request.method == "POST":
        Qty = request.POST['Qty']
        for item in request.POST:
            key = item
            value = request.POST[key]
            try:
                v = Variation.objects.get(item=item, category__iexact=key, title__iexact=value)
                item_var.append(v)
            except:
                pass


        cart_item, created = CartItem.objects.get_or_create(cart=cart, item=item)
        if created:
            print('yeah')
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you are overriding `item` variable in this for:
`for item in request.POST:`

Then when you do `CartItem.objects.get_or_create(cart=cart, item=item)` the `item` value will be the last object of the request.POST and not `item = Item.objects.get(slug=slug)`.